# Error while installing npm related files or others such as vite, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

I am getting an error while installing npm related files or others such as vite, react. I am downloading vs code.

I have recently downloaded vs code, node js and added node js as an environmental user variable
I have also installed npm grobally through the terminal of vs code but when i install vite it is not working or also npm install it can't work.[i entered node path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smVg1.png)

[i'm getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGusO.png)

Comment: npm cant' find a file, check the log file for a complete log - your images are mislabelled, and I didn't think it was possible to declare an environment variable with a space in its name - and what do you think having that environment variable achieves? Please add yor package.json and any other relevant information to the question

Answer (score -1):

***Mistake in setting the enviornment variable***

You must be save the path of nodejs in system variable --> path not in user variable by following this you can access the nodejs any where in your device

***Create Vite Project in a New Directory (my-vite-project):***

```
npm create vite@latest my-vite-project
```

This command will create a new directory named my-vite-project and scaffold the Vite project within that directory. All the project files and code will be contained within the specified directory.

***Create Vite Project in the Current Directory (.):***

```
npm create vite@latest .
```

This command will scaffold the Vite project directly in the current directory (represented by .). All the project files and code will be placed in the current working directory.

It's a good practice to explicitly specify the target directory to avoid confusion about where the project will be created. By providing a directory name (e.g., my-vite-project), you ensure that the project is organized within its own folder, making it clear and easy to navigate.